# Как подправить регулярное выражение для email в jQuery Validation Plugin?

Tags: javascript, html, html5, вёрстка, валидация

Для валидации форм использую [jQuery Validation Plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/).

Его встроенный метод для валидации email считает валидными также те ящики, у которых указан просто домен верхнего уровня, например `sky@net`

Но заказчик хочет сделать, чтобы подобные ящики считались не валидными.

Подскажите, как изменить это регулярное выражение, чтобы в **hostname** обязательно нужно было указывать точку и после которой обязательно должен быть какой-то домен верхнего уровня?

Плагин использует то же регулярное выражение, которое [спецификация HTML5 предлагает браузерам](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#valid-e-mail-address).

```
// Sets a custom email pattern for the built-in email validation rule.
// https://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.methods/
$.validator.methods.email = function( value, element ) {
    return this.optional( element ) || /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/.test( value );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте такое регулярное выражение:

```
(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])
```